# PHP check any key of array has null value

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I have a array like

```
$question = array(
'description'=>'some description',
'answer_one'=>'some answer',
'answer_two' => NULL)
```

I need to check any key of this array contains null value in quickest way.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$key = array_search(null, $question);
```

Comment: if (in_array(NULL, $question)) {

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$question = array(
'description'=>'some description',
'answer_one'=>'some answer',
'answer_two' => NULL);

foreach ($question as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == "") {
echo $key . " is empty!";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array(NULL, $question)) {

}
```